# C++ static_cast vs dynamic_cast

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

int main() {
    Base* bptr = new Derived();

    Derived* dptr = static_cast<Derived*>(bptr);

    std::cout << dptr << std::endl;
}
```

In the above code, I should be using `dynamic_cast` but am using
`static_cast` incorrectly. `static_cast` should never be used while
downcasting, since compiler has no way to determine we are doing
cast correctly.

Why isn't this a compile error? I am using gcc 4.9.2. Do you guys
think this is a bug in the compiler, or does C++ standards allow such code ?

Edit: Thanks for the responses. Actually, `Base` class above is polymorphic,
i.e. it has virtual functions, but I left them out for this example. I should
have thrown in a virtual destructor in the Base to make it clear that it
was polymorphic – my bad.

Comment: You are allowed to `static_cast` from `Base*` to `Derived*`, but you are correct that it will not perform any type-checking. It is still useful though, if you know through some other way that that pointer does actually point to a `Dervied` object. If the `Base*` didn't actually point to a `Derived*` then any dereferencing of the `Derived*` resulting from a `static_cast` would invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: In all reality, this is *exactly* what the `static_cast`is for; after all, conversions towards base class pointers/references are done implicitly.

Answer (score 8):

> In the above code, I should be using `dynamic_cast` but am using `static_cast` incorrectly. `static_cast` should never be used while downcasting, since compiler has no way to determine we are doing cast correctly.

Ironically, the `dynamic_cast` would actually be the ill-formed cast here, since your types are not polymorphic.

That said, `static_cast` can certainly be used to downcast. You are correct that the compiler cannot do type-checking, but there are many situations in which you have a `Base*` and know that it points to a `Derived*`, so you can just manually do the cast. One very common case is CRTP:

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
    Derived& self() { return *static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
    // ...
};


class Foo : Base<Foo> { ... };
```

`Base<T>` is *always* a `T`, so that downcast is safe.

The advantage of `static_cast` over `dynamic_cast` is that `static_cast` is free but `dynamic_cast` is expensive. The C++ mantra is don't pay for what you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast < new_type > ( expression )`

> If `new_type` is a pointer or reference to some class D and the type of
>   `expression` is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base B,
>   static_cast performs a downcast. This downcast is ill-formed if B is
>   ambiguous, inaccessible, or virtual base (or a base of a virtual base)
>   of D. Such static_cast makes no runtime checks to ensure that the
>   object's runtime type is actually D, and may only be used safely if
>   this precondition is guaranteed by other means, such as when
>   implementing static polymorphism. Safe downcast may be done with
>   dynamic_cast.

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) (Explanation item 2)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `static_cast` perfectly correctly. You are right, the compiler can in the general case not know whether the cast is correct, but `static_cast` is exactly there for this scenario.

You cannot use `dynamic_cast` here because that cast is for polymorphic classes (those which have a virtual member function). These classes carry run-time information; that information allows the code to choose the correct implementation of that function in the actual type of the object pointed to. This type information *in the object*  can be used by the cast function to determine whether the type conversion is possible, and then indeed perform the conversion properly (which can be tricky with multiple and virtual inheritance).

Classes without virtual functions, like your example classes, do not carry this run time information, and `dynamic_cast` cannot be used to cast to a more derived type. (It can still be used to cast to the same type or to a base class, i.e. it can be used for conversions which do actually not need a cast.)